# How to avoid using javascript Twice time ASP.NET MVC 5 in layout and view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, bundling-and-minification

here is my layout page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
@using System.Web.Optimization;
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="description" content="Metro, a sleek, intuitive, and powerful framework for faster and easier web development for Windows Metro Style.">
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, JS, JavaScript, framework, metro, front-end, frontend, web development">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title></title>


@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/metro-ui")
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/metro-ui/css")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")
```

and so on

and here is my RazorView

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/metro.min.js"></script>
<script   src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/metro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<br /><br />
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{

}
and so on...
```

my Razor View is inherited to Layout how can i use these scripts in my Razor view i don't need to use these scripts again in my Razor View please give me some solution...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove all header references from your view unless they are specific to only that view.

Views in MVC aren't complete pages if they include a layout.  The layout is the page.  There's a @RenderBody in the layout that gets replaced with your view information at render time.  All common javascript references should added to the layout using bundles.  See the Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") reference in the layout.

And even if you have javascript specific to a single page, it should be added using the scripts render section.  Then is gets added at page load and not the view render.

Comment: @fran i dont understand your answer please clearify me..if i remove all references from the view so my javascript will not run..

Comment: @fran ive already added scripts in layout `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/metro-ui")
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/metro-ui/css")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")` and in my view i have include layout page now if i remove javascripts from VIEW my page is not working..thats why i have added in View also..

Comment: can you define not working?  when you look at the page in the browser when you F12 do you see all the script files getting loaded?

Comment: yes it is not showing any error,i meant to say that when i remove scripts from my view  in the navigation bar i have dropdownmenu when i click to dropdownmenu it is not working but when i include metro.js in file view  then it will work fine.. but i have already include this file in bundle in layout page so when it is not inherriting?

Comment: possibly the bundle is cached?  Without seeing everything you've don't I can't say.

Comment: now work successfully i've wrote this link in routeconfig `MetroUICSSBundleConfig.RegisterBundles();` thanks for the keep replying